# Library for Creating Animated Presentations

Tags: language-agnostic, animated

Is there any library for creating animated presentations? Although the question is language-agnostic, I'm specifically biased towards WPF, yet I wouldn't mind you giving examples of libraries for any other language, or a visualization language of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know some folks, including Turing Award winner Alan Kay, that use [Squeak](http://www.squeak.org/) for presentations. Squeak is an interactive programming environment. It combines objects and all the pleasures of a modern language with the immediate feedback of what-you-see-is-what-you-get document editors.

I donnu if there are tutorials on building presentations with Squeak though.

Dan Ingall's [Lively](http://research.sun.com/projects/lively/) might also be of interest for you.

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this will sound to some like a sick joke, but it isn't: Have you considered Adobe Flash? Sure, it can be used for some questionable purposes, but ever since ActionScript 3 came out, it has a suprisingly decent OOP language attached, and it sure can make visuals and animations.

Answer (score 0):

(Question is very broad, hence my multiple answers - and I don't yet have the rep to add comments, only answers)

If it is high end, high-level mathematics you want, you must of course be aware of Mathematica.

At the other end of the scale, even (ugh) PowerPoint and the like can do what can technically be called an animated presentation.

Could you please be more specific about what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent presentation in [Squeak](http://squeak.org) (Squeak is an interactive programming environment. It combines objects and all the pleasures of a modern language with the immediate feedback of what-you-see-is-what-you-get document editors.): [Alan Kay on Ted on how to educate children with computers](http://www.ted.com/talks/alan_kay_shares_a_powerful_idea_about_ideas.html)